# Marking changes in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

When I'm changing a Word document in Word 2010, I'd like to get a small black bar at the border of the page. I don't want to have any balloons or colors - just the final text and a small black bar at the border of the page.

I know how to track changes, but I did not manage to get this particular formatting. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word 2010 gives some control over the display of change-tracking information.

In the Review tab of the ribbon, click the triangle beside Track Changes, and select "Change Tracking Options".

Try changing the following:

1. Insertions: to (none)
2. Deletions to (hidden)

I think that should do what you want, but if not, then you can experiment with the other display options.

See [this page](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T008765_Turning_Off_Track_Changes_Change_Bars.html) for a screen-shot of the "Track Changes Options" dialog.